# Text defining length, area and volume

Tags: geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for a geometry textbook that axiomatises concepts such as length, area and volume of objects in Euclidean space; for example, the surface area of a $2$-sphere in $3$-space. Such a text would then define length, area and volume, showing that the definitions satisfy the axioms, perhaps uniquely. It may even give different definitions that satisfy some common set of axioms. Is there such a book?

Comment: That this is a highly non-trivial exercise in three dimensions is proved by Hilbert's Third Problem and its (negative) resolution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_third_problem) and the Banach-Tarski Paradox (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach–Tarski_paradox). The attempts to make this rigorous extend from Euclid and Archimedes to modern measure theory (and set theory, when the existence or otherwise of unmeasurable sets is in question). The rigorous axiomatisation of measure is found to be much more subtle than at first suspected [like the proof of the Jordan Curve Theorem].

Comment: This lecture is almost certainly not what you are looking for, but is a much more abstract view which I had not seen until yesterday http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/07/the_categorical_origins_of_leb.html#more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These concepts are motivated through a measure theoretic approach, not just for Euclidian space, but for more general regions as well. I would recommend researching the Lebesgue measure in a real analysis textbook.